# Fresh deploy on Heroku fails with "use --allow-unverified PIL to allow"

Tags: python, django, heroku, pip

Tried deploying a Django project to a fresh app on Heroku (The code is running on other instances for past two years) - and was hit with this:

```
   Downloading/unpacking PIL==1.1.7 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))

   Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement PIL==1.1.7 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))

   Some insecure and unverifiable files were ignored (use --allow-unverified PIL to allow).
   Cleaning up...

   No distributions at all found for PIL==1.1.7 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
   Storing debug log for failure in /app/.pip/pip.log

   !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app
```

I'm aware of the recent changes in `pip` and would like to use packages that are secure, but until all are available properly packaged as per pip's expectations, we need some workarounds. Especially the lack of --allow-all-unverified flag makes this a trial-and-error mucking about with a blackbox exercise instead of a painless deployment.

Is there a sane way to get past this roadblock? (Not just PIL, but that's the first package that failed, there are several others like pyPdf that will fail if I manage to fix just this)

Any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I asked the maintainer of pip, and he replied with a simple solution. I am detailing how to go about it as a response to my own question. Here is what you need to do for now - until the packages are hosted internally and verified.

On local machine, create a new virtual environment and add one line on top of the `requirements.txt` file:

`--allow-all-external`

Save it and run:

`pip install -r requirements.txt --download="~/temp/packages"`

What this will do is simply take every package name from `requirements.txt` and download the package into `~/temp/packages` directory and verify it.

For every package that fails verification, add another line to `requirements.txt`, just below first line allowing all external packages, that goes like this:

`--allow-unverified package-name`

You might want to ping the maintainer to fix this ;)

Continue till pip completes successfully, then commit the updated `requirements.txt` to vcs and deploy.

That should be all.

Comment: Is it just me or is that a time consuming and painful process? If you look at other tools such as npm or bundler they don't give a crap about being unverified...anyways just ranting...

Comment: For other people like me: Make sure you're using a recent enough version of pip too....or you may try this and fail. I specifically was told it couldn't find some versionspec when I did this. Upgrading pip itself got me past it.