# How to allow unverified packages in requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip

I get the following error on installing ahocorasick on a server:

Some insecure and unverifiable files were ignored (use --allow-unverified ahocorasick to allow).

How do I modify the requirements.txt to allow unverified packages? The answer in [Fresh deploy on Heroku fails with "use --allow-unverified PIL to allow"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958382/fresh-deploy-on-heroku-fails-with-use-allow-unverified-pil-to-allow) states that we can add --allow-unverified ahocorasick in the requirements.txt. But that is not working for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need too add this line at the top of your requirements.txt

```
--allow-all-external
```

And then use `--allow-unverified` in desired packages.