# How to write setup.py to include a Git repository as a dependency

Tags: python, django, git, packaging, setuptools

I am trying to write `setup.py` for my package. My package needs to specify a dependency on another Git repository.

This is what I have so far:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='abc',
    packages=find_packages(),
    url='https://github.abc.com/abc/myabc',
    description='This is a description for abc',
    long_description=open('README.md').read(),
    install_requires=[
        "requests==2.7.0",
        "SomePrivateLib>=0.1.0",
        ],
    dependency_links = [
     "git+git://github.abc.com/abc/SomePrivateLib.git#egg=SomePrivateLib",
    ],
    include_package_data=True,
)
```

When I run:

```
pip install -e https://github.abc.com/abc/myabc.git#egg=analyse
```

I get

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> SomePrivateLib>=0.1.0 (from analyse) (from versions: ) No matching
> distribution found for SomePrivateLib>=0.1.0 (from analyse)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that setup.py and pip are completely different systems. One issue that I had was that I was able to get this working for pip but not for setup.py.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**Note:** this answer is now outdated. Have a look at this answer for up-to-date instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54701434/212774

---

You can find the right way to do it [here](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dependencies.html#packages-not-on-pypi).

```
dependency_links=['http://github.com/user/repo/tarball/master#egg=package-1.0']
```

The key is not to give a link to a Git repository, but a link to a tarball. GitHub creates a tarball of the master branch for you if you append `/tarball/master` as shown above.

Comment: Is it possible to disable server certificate verification on downloading the dependency ?

Comment: @Eugen, there's a `--trusted-host` option, but I am not sure if it helps. You might get a good answer if you ask in a new question.

Comment: I've found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29170630/how-to-allow-unverified-packages-in-requirements-txt

Comment: looks like this method is deprecated  per https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3939

Comment: This method is also useless for private repositories, since there's no way to authenticate.

Comment: @tedivm, according to the docs, it should in principle be possible to give a git url there instead of https, so I guess you can make it work with private repositories. (see https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi) If you manage to get it to work it may be worth to post this as a separate answer here.

Comment: I did manage to get it working and have added another answer.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work (anymore?), @DickFox's answer is the way to go.

Comment: The `/tarball/master` method does not work for gitlab

Comment: Deprecated. Correct answer is to use Pep508, answered by @Dick Fox below

Answer (score 232):

**Note:** this answer is now outdated. Have a look at this answer for up-to-date instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54701434/212774

---

After digging through the [pip issue 3939](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3939) linked by @muon in the comments above and then the [PEP-508 specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/), I found success getting my private repo dependency to install via `setup.py` using this specification pattern in `install_requires` (no more `dependency_links`):

```
install_requires = [
  'some-pkg @ git+ssh://git@github.com/someorgname/pkg-repo-name@v1.1#egg=some-pkg',
]
```

The `@v1.1` indicates the release tag created on github and could be replaced with a branch, commit, or different type of tag.

Comment: Note: This works fine for local/private packages, however, you cannot release a package to PyPI that uses this syntax in its setup.py

Comment: @Brian Could you please provide a link to official statement?

Comment: Note you can do `git+https://github.com` if you don't want to use SSH.

Comment: So what is the correct approach for doing a --upgrade? Even though I specify a tag version an upgrade just ignores newer tag versions

Comment: @Elephant Not super official, but these are at least comments on the pip GitHub project from actual members of the PyPA: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4187#issuecomment-415667805 and further explanation: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4187#issuecomment-415067034

Comment: how do you specify a commit instead of a release version?

Comment: Is there a protocol that works both for pip requirements files and `install_requires`? I usually use the pattern `install_requires=open("requirements.txt", "r").read().splitlines()`

Comment: thanks, how can we specify the whl file form the github location?

Comment: @Piacenti Did you came across any solution to the upgrade path ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked for me after 2 days of banging my head with `setup.py`. It worked like a charm for my private/internal repository. Just one difference is I didn't add the `#egg` part.

Comment: Could save someone's effort.  `my-dependent-sdk @ git+https://<mypersonaltoken>@github.private.com/myorg/my-dependent-sdk.git@master`

Comment: This does not seem to work if then installing via `python setup.py develop`. Instead using `pip install -e .` worked for me.

Comment: In one of the answers below, it suggests removing the #egg= section. I needed that piece of information to get it to work for my repo.

Comment: @EduardoPignatelli if someone is looking for that as well you can run for each line:
`line = re.sub(r'(git\+.*egg=(.*))', '\2 @ \1', line)`

Answer (score 94):

### This answer has been updated as Python has evolved over the years.

**Scroll to the bottom for the most current answer**, or read through to see how this has evolved.

---

Unfortunately the accepted answer does not work with private repositories, which is one of the most common use cases for this.

### 2019 - dependency_links (deprecated as of pip v19+)

I eventually did get it working with a `setup.py` file that looks like this method:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name = 'MyProject',
    version = '0.1.0',
    url = '',
    description = '',
    packages = find_packages(),
    install_requires = [
        # Github Private Repository - needs entry in `dependency_links`
        'ExampleRepo'
    ],

    dependency_links=[
        # Make sure to include the `#egg` portion so the `install_requires` recognizes the package
        'git+ssh://git@github.com/example_org/ExampleRepo.git#egg=ExampleRepo-0.1'
    ]
)
```

Newer versions of pip make this even easier by removing the need to use "dependency_links"-

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name = 'MyProject',
    version = '0.1.0',
    url = '',
    description = '',
    packages = find_packages(),
    install_requires = [
        # Github Private Repository
        'ExampleRepo @ git+ssh://git@github.com/example_org/ExampleRepo.git#egg=ExampleRepo-0.1'
    ]
)
```

However, with the very latest pip you'll run into issues with the EGG format handler. This is because while the egg is ignored pip is now doing direct URL matching and will consider two URLs, one with the egg fragment and the other without, to be completely different versions even if they point to the same package. As such it's best to leave any egg fragments off.

### 2021 June - setup.py

**So, the best way (current to June 2021) to add a dependency from Github to your setup.py that will work with public and private repositories:**

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name = 'MyProject',
    version = '0.1.0',
    url = '',
    description = '',
    packages = find_packages(),
    install_requires = [
        # Github Private Repository
        'ExampleRepo @ git+ssh://git@github.com/example_org/ExampleRepo.git'
    ]
)
```

### 2022 February - setup.cfg

Apparently setup.py is being deprecated (although my guess is it'll be around for awhile) and setup.cfg is the new thing.

```
[metadata]
name = MyProject
version = 0.1.1


[options]
packages = :find

install_requires =
  ExampleRepo @ git+ssh://git@github.com/example_org/ExampleRepo.git
```

### 2022 June - pyproject.toml

setup.cfg is [already "pre" deprecated.](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3214) as [setuptools now has experimental support for pyproject.toml](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html#configuring-setuptools-using-pyproject-toml-files) files.

This is the future, but since this is still experimental it should not be used in real projects for now. Even though `setup.cfg` is on its way out you should use it for a declarative format, otherwise setup.py is still the way to go. This answer will be updated when setuptools has stabilized their support of the new standard.

### 2023 January - pyproject.toml

It is now possible to define all of your dependencies in `pyproject.toml`. Other options such as setup.cfg still work.

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "setuptools-scm"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
dependencies = [
    'ExampleRepo @ git+ssh://git@github.com/example_org/ExampleRepo.git',
]

[project.optional-dependencies]
dev = ['ExtraExample @ git+ssh://git@github.com/example_org/ExtraExample.git']
```

### 2024 April

At this point the `pyproject.toml` file is the standard. There is literally no reason to use `setup.cfg` or `setup.py`. If you are using them you should consolidate to a single `pyproject.toml` file.

Comment: could you please elaborate what `-0.1` stands for in your approach? Do you take the version number from a git release or from the `setup.py` description?

Comment: From the setup.py file- if you want to use a specific branch or tag you format things a little differently.

Comment: "Unfortunately the other answer does not work with private repositories" This is no longer true [Fox's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54794506/7898913) answer does work on private repo without needing `dependency_links` (which is [deprecated](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html?highlight=%40%20git#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi))

Comment: Thanks @Keto! I don't know why your edit got rejected but the mods, but I went ahead and overrode that rejection to add the deprecation notice to the answer.

Comment: This really ought to be the top answer, it's actually relevant in the current time.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when running `python setup.py install` - it only works for me for `pip install -e [module_name]`. Is that true for all? This is on pip 21.1.3

Comment: I recommend always using pip and not using setup.py install. This answer has a lot more details on why- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15731459/212774

Comment: I get "Host key verification failed." using ssh, but using https works, e.g:  `pkg @ git+https://github.com/user/pkg.git`  - also best answer here

Comment: You can resolve the host key verification by adding the host key to your known key list. Using github as an example, in a shell run `ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

Comment: Thanks for keeping this up-to-date!

Comment: Hey @RobertHafner would I then just import the package as `import ExtraExample`? I follow your steps but still seem to get `ModuleNotFoundError`. Thanks!

Comment: @kykyi - the name and the module names should match but that's not a requirement- there are some libraries, like pyyaml, that have different names than their modules.

Comment: I just saw that you can even install a dependency with it's optional dependencies using `pip install foo[dev]@git+https://github.com/foo/foo`

Answer (score 8):

A more general answer: To get the information from the *requirements.txt* file I do:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from os import path

loc = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))

with open(loc + '/requirements.txt') as f:
    requirements = f.read().splitlines()

required = []
dependency_links = []

# Do not add to required lines pointing to Git repositories
EGG_MARK = '#egg='
for line in requirements:
    if line.startswith('-e git:') or line.startswith('-e git+') or \
            line.startswith('git:') or line.startswith('git+'):
        line = line.lstrip('-e ')  # in case that is using "-e"
        if EGG_MARK in line:
            package_name = line[line.find(EGG_MARK) + len(EGG_MARK):]
            repository = line[:line.find(EGG_MARK)]
            required.append('%s @ %s' % (package_name, repository))
            dependency_links.append(line)
        else:
            print('Dependency to a git repository should have the format:')
            print('git+ssh://git@github.com/xxxxx/xxxxxx#egg=package_name')
    else:
        required.append(line)

setup(
    name='myproject',  # Required
    version='0.0.1',  # Required
    description='Description here....',  # Required
    packages=find_packages(),  # Required
    install_requires=required,
    dependency_links=dependency_links,
)
```

Answer (score 7):

Actually if you like to make your packages installable recursively (YourCurrentPackage includes your SomePrivateLib), e.g. when you want to include YourCurrentPackage into another one (like OuterPackage → YourCurrentPackage → SomePrivateLib) you'll need both:

```
install_requires=[
    ...,
    "SomePrivateLib @ git+ssh://github.abc.com/abc/SomePrivateLib.git@0.1.0#egg=SomePrivateLib"
],
dependency_links = [
    "git+ssh://github.abc.com/abc/SomePrivateLib.git@0.1.0#egg=SomePrivateLib"
]
```

And make sure you have a tag created with your version number.

Also if your Git project is private and you like to install it inside the container, e.g., a [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29) or [GitLab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitLab) runner, you will need authorized access to your repository. Please consider to use Git + HTTPS with access tokens (like on GitLab: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html):

```
import os
from setuptools import setup

TOKEN_VALUE = os.getenv('EXPORTED_VAR_WITH_TOKEN')

setup(
    ....

    install_requires=[
            ...,
            f"SomePrivateLib @ git+https://gitlab-ci-token:{TOKEN_VALUE}@gitlab.server.com/abc/SomePrivateLib.git@0.1.0#egg=SomePrivateLib"
    ],
    dependency_links = [
            f"git+https://gitlab-ci-token:{TOKEN_VALUE}@gitlab.server.com/abc/SomePrivateLib.git@0.1.0#egg=SomePrivateLib"
    ]
)
```

### Updated:

You have to put **#egg=SomePrivateLib** at the end of dependency line if you like to have this dependency in *requirements.txt* file. Otherwise **pip install -r requirements.txt** won't work for you and you wil get something like:

> ERROR: Could not detect requirement name for
> 'git+https://gitlab-ci-token:gitlabtokenvalue@gitlab.server.com/abc/SomePrivateLib.git@0.1.0',
> please specify one with #egg=your_package_name

If you use *reuirements.txt*, this part is resposible for name of dependency’s folder that would be created inside *python_home_dir/src* and for name of egg-link in *site-packages/*

You can use a environment variable in your *requirements.txt* to store your dependency’s token value safe in your repo:

Example row in *requrements.txt* file for this case:

```
....

-e git+https://gitlab-ci-token:${EXPORTED_VAR_WITH_TOKEN}@gitlab.server.com/abc/SomePrivateLib.git@0.1.0#egg=SomePrivateLib
....
```

Answer (score 4):

I was successful with these three options in [GitLab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitLab). I am using version 11 of GitLab.

Option 1 - no token specified. The shell will prompt for username/password.

```
from setuptools import setup

TOKEN_VALUE = os.getenv('EXPORTED_VAR_WITH_TOKEN')

setup(
    install_requires=[
        "SomePrivateLib @ git+https://gitlab.server.com/abc/SomePrivateLib.git@0.1.0#egg=SomePrivateLib"
    ]
)
```

Option 2 - user access token specified. The token generated by going to GitLab → account top right → settings → access tokens. Create the token with read_repository rights.

Example:

```
import os
from setuptools import setup

TOKEN_VALUE = os.getenv('EXPORTED_VAR_WITH_TOKEN')

setup(
    install_requires=[
        f"SomePrivateLib @ git+https://gitlab-ci-token:{TOKEN_VALUE}@gitlab.server.com/abc/SomePrivateLib.git@0.1.0#egg=SomePrivateLib"
    ]
)
```

Option 3 - repository-level token specified. The token generated by going to the repository → settings → repository → deploy tokens. From here, create a token with read_repository rights.

Example:

```
import os
from setuptools import setup

TOKEN_USER = os.getenv('EXPORTED_TOKEN_USER')
TOKEN_VALUE = os.getenv('EXPORTED_VAR_WITH_TOKEN')

setup(
    install_requires=[
        f"SomePrivateLib @ git+https://{TOKEN_USER}:{TOKEN_VALUE}@gitlab.server.com/abc/SomePrivateLib.git@0.1.0#egg=SomePrivateLib"
    ]
)
```

In all three, I was able to do simply: "SomePrivateLib @ git+https://gitlab.server.com/abc/SomePrivateLib.git" without the #egg marking at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me when I run python setup.py install:

```
setuptools.setup(
    ...,
    install_requires=[
        'numpy',
        'pandas',
        'my_private_pkg'
        ],
    dependency_links=["git+https://github.com/[username]/[my_private_pkg].git@main#egg=my_private_pkg"],
    ...
)
```