# Include python packages from gitlab's package registry and other external indexes directly into setup.py dependencies

Tags: git, pip, gitlab, setuptools, python-packaging

The [gitlab package registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/) can be used to [publish](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/pypi_repository/#publish-a-pypi-package-by-using-twine) and [install](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/pypi_repository/#install-a-pypi-package) python packages. Such an installation works perfect using `--extra-index-url` or `--index-url` as described in the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/pypi_repository/#install-a-pypi-package) and I have also tested it successfully using a `requirements.txt` file as described [here](https://medium.com/maisonsdumonde/gitlab-ci-cd-and-gitlab-pypi-repository-4916a51d22eb).

Nonetheless, it would be easier for many purposes to add them directly into the packages [setup.py](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#creating-setup-py).

Is there any way to add these packages from gitlab's registry or other external indexes directly into the requirements within a `setup.py`?

Note: I know that it is possible to install directly from git repositorys from a `setup.py`. But I would like to use the versioned package registry instead.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write setup.py to include a Git repository as a dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32688688/how-to-write-setup-py-to-include-a-git-repository-as-a-dependency)

Comment: No. As explained, I already know how to do that. This question deals with gitlab's package registry or other indexes.

Comment: Answer is still basically the same: you can't. You can't add this info in `setup.py`. Read this: https://discuss.python.org/t/dependency-notation-including-the-index-url/5659

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Although I am not really happy with the result ;-)

Comment: I will leave it open anyway for the case that it changes in future or someone comes arround with a creative solution.