# Write setup.py using git repo in install_requires to detect already installed

Tags: python, git, setuptools, setup.py

I have a package with a git+ssh dependency, like this:

```
setup(
    name="setuprequires",
    version="0.1",
    packages=["setuprequires"],
    install_requires=[
        r"hello-world @ git+ssh://git@github.com/hello/hello-world.git#egg=hello-world"
    ],  
)
```

(I'm following the most up-to-date answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54794506/15055491) regarding git repo dependencies.)

However, I'd like to skip installing `hello-world` if it's already installed in my current environment. Yet, if I run `pip install -e .` twice, the second time will still clone `hello-world`. In contrast, if I had just used `install_requires=[r"hello-world"]`, it would've correctly detected that this requirement was already satisfied.

It seems to me that `git+ssh` doesn't play nicely with detecting already-satisfied requirements. I would think that having `#egg=hello-world` would've fixed this problem. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detect a repository is up to date (or a certain commit is used) you need to clone it first, therefore to have a cache present even if it attempted to fetch it from cache you'd still first need to have it cloned.

After the first clone, it *should* compare it with the existing, cloned repository.

As you haven't specified any commit, I'm guessing it's still pulling because of that. See [`Git._should_fetch()`](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/01308b81f2ccc1247733cdd8513d83386f1b113a/src/pip/_internal/vcs/git.py#L177) class method.

Instead, try to specify the commit/tag you want to use, [as mentioned in the docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/vcs-support/#git), it should start caching:

```
git+https://git.example.com/MyProject.git@<hash>#egg=MyProject
git+https://git.example.com/MyProject.git@<tag>#egg=MyProject
git+ssh://git.example.com/MyProject.git@<hash>#egg=MyProject
git+ssh://git.example.com/MyProject.git@<tag>#egg=MyProject
```

***Edit:***

What I've noticed is that if you use a branch, the caching is broken. It's not `refs/...`, so it's not an explicit remote branch pulling, nor it's a hash. However for commit hashes it works flawlessly and stores the created wheel in the `--cache-dir` destination which is then picked on the 2nd+ execution of the `pip install` command. ([bug created](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10400))

**Example:**

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="testing-git",
    install_requires=[
        # cached properly
        "requests @ git+ssh://git@github.com/psf/requests.git@cd4762d5a3b56d8933d1d9c1dff365fc5db4c768#egg=requests-3.0"
        # not cached
        # "requests @ git+ssh://git@github.com/psf/requests.git@3.0#egg=requests-3.0"
    ]
)
```